# Install mongodb on ubuntu with apt-get fails

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to install mongoDB on Ubuntu Server 14.04 with apt-get.

My command ist `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org -y`

After installation I'm trying to run `sudo service mongod start`
The output is `mongod start/running, process 11977`

Trying to get status `sudo service mongod status` prints out `mongod stop/waiting`
Trying to stop mongod `sudo service mongod stop` prints `stop: Unknown instance:`

When I type `mongo` in command line I get this

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: test
2014-08-02T11:49:28.781+0200 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111     Connection refused
2014-08-02T11:49:28.782+0200 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1),   connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try running mongo using this "mongo --host localhost --port 27017" See if that works.

Comment: 'mongo --host localhost --port 27017
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
Sat Aug  2 21:27:42.845 Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed'

Comment: Are there any errors in the MongoDB log when you try to start the service? The log file should be: `/var/log/mongodb`. Unless the `mongod` server has successfully started, you won't be able to connect with a `mongo` shell.

Comment: Ok I found out why it doesn't work. I have not enough space on my server.

Comment: @MiralemCebic Oh! Thanks for confirming the problem :)

Answer (score -1):

mongod is not running, thats why you cant connect.  Before you run it as a service, just run mongod from the command line and see how it fails.   Once you get it working, you can convert to a service.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have followed the instructions on the  [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) and it does not work :/

Comment: Downvote for "just run mongodb from the command line". More detail please. For the record, it should probably be `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. That doesn't work for me either (no output at all, just fails, I'm going to open a separate question for this), but well...